# What prevents the turning on of a lamp and also cause it's flashing due to a capacitor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, capacitance

[image][image]

For this question, why does the lamp not turn on straight away as would the potential difference across the lamp not be 120V to begin with as the lamp is parallel to the capacitor? The answer given does not really help me understand even why it flashes in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The neon lamp is in parallel with the capacitor so the voltage across the neon lamp is always the same as the voltage across the capacitor.

Initially the capacitor is uncharged and so the voltage across it and the the neon bulb is zero.

The capacitor charges up and the voltage across the capacitor and the neon bulb increases until the voltage reaches $100\,\rm V$.
At this voltage the gas in the neon becomes a conductor and the neon bulb produces light.
During the time the neon bulb is conducting it acts like a dead sort (very small resistance value) across the capacitor which therefore discharges through the neon bulb.

This rapid discharge of the capacitor (with the neon bulb emitting light) occurs until the voltage across the neon bulb reaches $80 \, \rm V$ at which time the neon bulb ceases to be a conductor.

The capacitor then starts to charge again until the voltage across the capacitor and neon light becomes $100\,\rm V$ when the neon bulb lights up and becomes a very good conductor (ie has a very small resistance), the capacitor is rapidly discharged until the voltage across the capacitor and the neon bulb reaches $80\,\rm V$, the neon bulb ceases to emit light (and has a very high resistance) and the sequence continues.

Remembering that the time constant is the product of resistance and capacitance,  the charging of the capacitor is determined by the capacitance of the capacitor and the resistance of resistor $R$ whereas the time for discharge of the capacitor (when the neon bulb is emitting light) is determined by the capacitance of the capacitor and the very low resistance of neon light bulb which is emitting light.

Answer (score 0):

> For this question, why does the lamp not turn on straight away as
>   would the potential difference across the lamp not be 120V to begin
>   with as the lamp is parallel to the capacitor?

I do not understand your reasoning here.  The voltage across a capacitor cannot change "straight away" for finite current through.  That is, there is some time constant associated with the resistor-capacitor (RC) circuit with regards to the voltage across the capacitor.

For example (and ignoring the neon lamp for now), if the voltage across the capacitor is initially zero, it will take one time constant (the product of R and C) to change to about 63.2% of 120 V.

Do you see now why the lamp does not turn on straight away?